# Loadstring function replacement in latest version

Tags: lua

I updated from lua 5.1 to 5.3.2 , One of my scripts didn't work cause of `attempt to call a nil value (global 'loadstring')` So, did they replace it with a new function?

There you can find the function https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html
There you can test it ( won't work) http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

Comment: Step through the versions of the Reference Manual, reading the "Incompatibilities with the Previous Version" section.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since Lua 5.2, `loadstring` has been replaced by [`load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load).

From [Lua 5.2 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.2):

> Function `loadstring` is deprecated. Use `load` instead; it now accepts string arguments and are exactly equivalent to `loadstring`.