# Eval function in LUA 5.1

Tags: lua, eval, lua-5.1

I want to use an eval function in Lua,

Can't make it work. Did not find documentation on it, does Lua even have an eval function ?

Code tried :

```
a=1
print(a)
eval('print(a)')
eval 'print(a)'
```

Official Lua demo interpreter : https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

Output :

```
1
input:3: attempt to call a nil value (global 'eval')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lua has the [`loadstring`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring) function, which parses a string and returns a function that would execute that code, provided the given string is a syntactically correct Lua function body.

```
a = 1
local f = loadstring "print(a)"
f() --> 1
```

Be wary that functions made with `loadstring` won't have access to local variables, only global variables. Also, the normal warnings about using `eval` in other languages apply to Lua too -- it's very likely to cause security and stability problems in real world systems.

For Lua 5.2+, see [Loadstring function replacement in latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641153/loadstring-function-replacement-in-latest-version) -- it has been replaced by `load`, which is more permissive in Lua 5.2+.

Comment: When trying your code on the official LUA interpreter I got the result :
'input:2: attempt to call a nil value (global 'loadstring')' ;
Is there something I still miss ?

Comment: Which version of Lua are you using? `lua -v` on the command line will tell you.

Comment: The Lua version is 5.1.4

Comment: I added information about Lua versions 5.2+. The online demo that you linked to is, at least at this moment, version 5.3: `print(_VERSION)`. `loadstring` works with no set up in 5.1.4.

Comment: Ok was trying it on the official interpreter which was 5.3.5, but my version is 5.1.4, so actually it was good with loadsting. Thanks !

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't think `dostring` is available from the Lua side (though `dofile` is): https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_dostring

Comment: `it's very likely to cause security and stability problems in real world systems` What are the problems you are talking about?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Sanitizing code is a really hard problem; if there's any chance of any bit of user input going into `loadstring`, you likely have made a mistake. If it's possible to safely sanitize the user input, `loadstring` is probably not necessary (a simple DSL or just table lookups are likely sufficient). In any case, if you have `loadstring` doing anything important, it's completely invisible, because it's a string and not code (and likely invisibly affecting global variables).